# Mesh will not seamlessly UV unwrap

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I've tried modifying the seams and changing the unwrap settings, but no matter what I do when I hit "smart UV Unwrap" the mesh will not unwrap seamlessly. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Smart UV Project doesn't take the seams into account, it will unwrap according to the angle defined in the Operator Box, if you want the seams to be taken into account, use the first option (called simply "Unwrap")? Or please explain more in detail what you want to do and maybe share your file

Comment: @moonboots I'm trying to apply the texture seamlessly to the mesh. Here's the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GjSqRAGZplTFX8_8tkak-jL_ZjPP4jBU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inner faces, remove them and unwrap again, now the texture should be seamless.

For such an object you could also try the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* and set the *Image Texture* to *Box* instead of *Flat*, it will project the texture on the 3 axis.